# TensorFlow and Keras GPU usage issues

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, ubuntu-20.04

I am using an existing model to train a CRNN model which is based on Tensorflow and Keras. I am using anaconda-navigator to train the model.

When the model is being trained, it does not seem to use GPU as my GPU usage is at 5-6%.
I am attaching images of top -i command, Nvidia Xserver, and also my gpu is not being picked up by Tensorflow as tf.test.gpu_device_name() only shows CPU as shown in the below screenshot [tf.test.gpu_device_name()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWGbw.png)
[Tensorflow and Keras Versions in anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG4Gn.png)
[top -i output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QofSn.png)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your TensorFlow and Keras versions in anaconda, i found there is a tensorflow-gpu package missing. It looks like you have only installed TensorFlow CPU version and not the GPU version. If you had installed the GPU version of TensorFlow, then the anaconda navigator would also show a metapackage of TensorFlow GPU library.

That is the reason why you don't see the details of your GPU with the command tf.test.gpu_device_name()

TensorFlow GPU will automatically load the CUDA libraries corresponding to your GPU.
Since you are using anaconda environment install the GPU version as follows

`Activate your conda environment`

`conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu`

This command would install TensorFlow v2.2.0 to your conda environment.
If you want the latest tf v2.4 then try using pip to install the specific version inside your conda environment

`pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.4`

Keras will automatically be installed with TensorFlow 2.0 verison. You can use Keras library with TensorFlow backend. If you want a specific version of Keras, you can always install it using pip

Comment: ->Following your instructions I installed Tensorflow-gpu
->Ran into dependencies issues with numpy and tensorflow-estimator versions
->Corrected the versions listed for tensorflow-gpu
->This message was displayed afterwards 
`ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.4.0 requires numpy~=1.19.2, but you have numpy 1.18.5 which is incompatible.`

Comment: Same for `tensorflow 2.4.0 requires tensorflow-estimator<2.5.0,>=2.4.0rc0, but you have tensorflow-estimator 2.3.0 which is incompatible.`

Ran the training again but only cpu is being used. GPU sits idle at 3-6% usage

Comment: Did you uninstall the previous version of tensorflow? Also which method did you use for installing the library? conda or pip ?

Comment: Should I remove tensorflow and leave tensorflow-gpu?

Comment: Yes, you need to uninstalll your previous installed packages and install tensorflow again with gpu.